# Create temp table with stored procedure on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I would like to create a temporary table on either of those events, depending on which would be the most prudent in a real-world application: the page load event, or the second time a button is clicked.   I have a simple stored procedure of

```
create proc spMakeTempTable
create table #tempTable (columnName varchar(50))
```

and the c#

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDrugList.Focus();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spMakeTempTable", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

I need the temp table to be specific to a particular session, so that if different people visited the site a different temp table would be created for them.  When I run the app and the page loads, however, the temporary table isn't created.  If I change the sproc to create a global temporary table, it works.  I don't think that this is what I want, though, since I would like each temporary table to be visitor-specific.  If the visitor refreshes the page it's fine that the temp table will be destroyed and recreated.

Secondly, is it smart to have a proc execute on the page load event, or should I put this logic into a button click event?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing why you would want to create a temporary table for a session, when you can just use the `Session` object?

Comment: what do you want to store in this temp table?

Comment: There will be a button on the page that will send the text they type into a text box and insert that into the temp table.  Then another stored procedure will perform a cross join of everything they entered into the temp table.

Comment: @George because I'm a noob, naturally :).

Comment: Well don't do that -- it's a terrible maintenance nightmare.  If I came upon that logic in a web app, it would get *nuked and replaced immediately.* :)

Comment: I would read up on Sessions.  They've already been defined and are standard in use for what you are doing.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is probably being created. The problem is that local temp tables are destroyed as soon as the connection is closed, which for you happens at the end of your `using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))` block.

Ignoring for the moment why this approach might or might not be a good idea, any SqlConnection object that you create in the scope of your webpage code will be disposed of as soon as the response is returned. If you really want to use local temp tables and have them persist between user requests, you would have to do something like adding the SqlConnection objects to a collection in a static class and not disposing them (which includes not putting them in a using statement). You would then retrieve the user's SqlConnection object from that collection on future requests when you need to retrieve or write more data to the temp table.  You would still have to worry the additional problems of how long to leave the connections open and when to dispose the SqlConnection objects.

While I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, you might want to consider alternate approaches to storing user-specific data in temp tables.

Comment: While I was completely aware that `using` cleaned up the connection and that temp tables exist only as long as the connection does, I didn't really put two and two together so now it makes perfect sense while my solution was a flawed one.  Seems like going with a Session variable is the best way to go.